# Determining if several data frames have the same column names in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have several df and would like to determine if they all have the same column names. I have seen several examples where this is done with two data frames but wanted some information on how to do this across multiple df-s.

For example if I have a list of df-s

```
dataframes = [df_1, df_2, df_3, df_4, df_5_1, df_5_2, df_6_1, df_6_2]
```

I would like to possibly loop through each one to see if they all contain the same column names.

Comment: `"I would like to possibly loop through each one to see if they all contain the same column names."` what if not? can you post the expected output?

Comment: You can get a list of column names of a dataframe by `df.columns` and then its just a matter of list comparisions.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your don't have duplicate column names, which is never a good idea in `pandas`, and "same" doesn't care about the position they occur in the Index, it suffices to check if the length of the columns index is the same as the length of the set intersection between two DataFrame indices.

Because you want to know whether they are **all** the same or if **any** single one differs, it suffices to check against the first.

```
all([len(dataframes[0].columns.intersection(df.columns)) 
      == dataframes[0].shape[1] for df in dataframes])
```

Comment: i was thinking `pd.DataFrame([i.columns for i in dfs]).nunique(1).eq(1).all()`

Comment: @anky_91 That's a valid solution (I think perhaps not along axis=1 though for `nunique`). Though it depends if the "same columns" also requires ordering. If it does, then mine is incorrect and that's preferable (or a simple element-wise equality check). Either way `np.sort` would work to make that good if it's regardless or order.

Answer (score 3):

Simply compare the *column sets*:

```
if all([set(dataframes[0].columns) == set(df.columns) for df in dataframes]):
    print('All have the same columns')
else:
    print('Some have different columns')
```

A slightly easier variant of [ALollz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59198950/3673329)' neat answer (I would not be surprised though if his is faster).

Answer (score 0):

You can check `data` using this:

```
columns = list(map(lambda x: list(x.columns), [df, df, df]))
data = pd.DataFrame(columns)
data = data.fillna("")
data.drop_duplicates(keep="first", inplace=True)
if len(data) > 1:
  print("DIFFERENT COLUMNS")
```

and the index you will find in `data` if it is more than 1 row it will show which data frame in `columns`